# Given the normalised floating point number system, calculate smallest possible value of y - x

Tags: number-systems, floating-point

*First I present the problem and then my workings and thoughts:*

Given the normalized floating point number system

> $(\beta, t, L, U) = (10, 7, -6, 4)$   where $\beta$ is the base and $t$ is the number of digits
>   Calculate the smallest possible value of 
>   $y - x$ for which  $\bf x < 100 < y$

---

*My workings:*

$100 = 0.1 \times 10 ^2 = 0.1000000 \times 10^2$

I can calculate that the smallest possible number greater than $100$ (i.e. $y$) is equal to: $$0.1000001 \times 10^2$$
But, I think I miscalculated the greatest possible number greater than $100$ (i.e. $x$); I calculated it to be$$ 0.9999999 \times 10^1 $$
I know the result should be $y - x = 0.11 \times 10^{-3}$, whereas I get $0.11 \times 10^{-4} $

Any hints on how to solve my mistake?

Comment: put math statements in `$..$` and `$$..$$`

Comment: thanks for that I was looking how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$100= 0.1 \cdot 10^3= 0.1000000 \cdot 10^3$$

The smallest possible number greater than $100$ is equal to :
$$y=0.1000001 \cdot  10^3 $$

The greatest possible number smaller than $100$:

$$0.0999999 \cdot 10^3=0.999999 \cdot 10^2$$

$$y-x=0.1000001 \cdot  10^3 -0.999999 \cdot 10^2=100.00001-99.9999=0.00011=0.11 \cdot 10^{-3}$$

Comment: Then, just to clarify I understood fully,
for the same number system but this time for $x<0.01<y :  y=0.1000001*10^-1 and x=0.0999999*10^-2.  Correct?

Comment: It is like that:
$$$$
$x<0.01<y$

$$0.01=0.1 \cdot  10^{-1}=0.1000000 \cdot 10^{-1}$$

The smallest possible number greater than $0.01$ is equal to 

$$y=0.1000001 \cdot 10^{-1}$$

The greatest possible number smaller than $0.01$:

$$0.0999999 \cdot 10^{-1}=0.999999 \cdot 10^{-2}$$

Comment: Which gives y-x=0.2*10^(-7), whereas the solution says it should be y-x=0.11*10^(-7). I am so confused about this